# ssrs chart axis labels duplicated

Tags: reporting-services, axis-labels

I am trying to get my chart to only show the month name.  I have changed the horizontal axis options to do that but they are all duplicated.  Can anyone tell me how I can get this set up to only show each month one time?

Here is the chart without any formatting:
[image]

It correctly shows the 4 data points.

I then go to the Horizontal Axis properties, change it to number and then select the MMM for the three character month name which correctly displays:
[image]

when I run the report after making that change I get an extra month (december) and all the month names are duplicated:
[image]

What do I need to do so that I only get Jan - Apr one time on my horizontal axis?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Leslie

edit:  Here is the raw data:

[image]

I have tried changing the interval but have seen no effect on the output.  I have tried unselecting the "Always include zero" option to get rid of december but that didn't work either.

edit 2: I said above there was no effect when I changed the axis interval to 1, actually that results in many entries for the Year-Month data in the axis area.
[image]

Comment: It's not supposed to work like this. I can't figure out how it got this way if it was working before. Is your Category Group expression grouping by month or does it have individual dates?

Comment: The axis interval might be set to Auto, this sometimes goes wrong so I force the interval to be whatever I want, in your case 1. Also check the Axis Type is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on horizontal axis, select axis property, from the "Axis range and interval", for interval, type in "1" (without quotes), for interval type, select "Month", then hit OK. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSMZS.png)